# How to send a HttpResponse in a permission custom decorator?

Tags: django

I'm creating a decorator for 5 views I have. That decorator redirects the user in case he's not authenticated or has no permission. But in case the user is authenticated and has permission, he should get the page. The problem is that I get a 'The view myapp.views.wrapper didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead'

How can I use a return HttpResponse  ... to redirect the user to the view he tried to access? This is the code:

```
def ask_permission(func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login')
        if not (request.user.groups.filter(name__in=["group_1", "group_2", "group_3"]).exists()):
            return redirect('access_denied')

        # redirect HttpResponse should be here
    return wrapper
```

What's the code for redirect HttpResponse I'm missing?

Solved by Mehdi Pourfar's answer.

Also, if you want to use a decorator in a CBV, besides using the decorator before the name of the class, you have to override the dispatch method like this:

```
@method_decorator(ask_permission)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or even better:

```
@method_decorator(ask_permission, name='dispatch')
def ModelCreateView(....
```

This way we override the dispatch method in the decorator and we don't need to write it inside the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return func(request, *args, **kwargs) if none of the conditions above are met.

Comment: Now I get '__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given' error message, even if I only use 'return func(request)'

Comment: __init__ of which class?

Comment: After a few tries more, I see that I get that message when I use CBV. If I use a non-CBV works well.

Comment: My bad. I checked the docs and seems that you can only decorate non-CBV classes. In order to do so, you should decorate the dispatch method instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class